# How can I validate a multiselect InputField using its onchange event?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have an inputField bound to a multi-select custom Field.

I want to validate that the user picks a max of 3 items from the list, and I want to show a message or an alert when the user selects a forth item right away(not on submission of the form). I found that the actionSupport can help me with that, but I'm not sure if it can allow me to keep track of how many items are selected

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Destination_ Specialties}">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{}" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to use a JavaScript function. Add this to your page between `<script>` and `</script>` tags:

```
var selected = {};

function validate(obj)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++) {
    if (obj.options[i].selected) {
      selected[obj.id+'_'+obj.options[i].value] = obj.options[i].label; 
    }
    else {
      selected[obj.id+'_'+obj.options[i].value] = null;
    }
  }

  var size = 0;
  for (var key in selected) {
    if (selected[key] != null) { size++; }
  }

  //console.log(size);

  if(size > 3){
    alert("You can only select a maximum of three options.");
  }
}
```

Then change your `<apex:inputField>` to look like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Destination_ Specialties}" onchange="validate(this);"></apex:inputField>
```

Here's a complete sample Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page >
  <script>
    var selected = {};

    function validate(obj)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++) {
        if (obj.options[i].selected) {
          selected[obj.id+'_'+obj.options[i].value] = obj.options[i].label; 
        }
        else {
          selected[obj.id+'_'+obj.options[i].value] = null;
        }
      }

      var size = 0;
      for (var key in selected) {
        if (selected[key] != null) { size++; }
      }

      //console.log(size);

      if(size > 3){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of three options.");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:selectList id="chooseColor1" size="5" multiselect="true" onchange="validate(this);">
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="white" itemLabel="White"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="orange" itemLabel="Orange"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="green" itemLabel="Green"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
    <apex:selectList id="chooseColor2" size="5" multiselect="true" onchange="validate(this);">
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="white" itemLabel="White"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="orange" itemLabel="Orange"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="green" itemLabel="Green"/>
      <apex:selectOption itemValue="blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I'm using an inputField though... not a selectList.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can use the onchange attribute on an `inputField` as well.

Comment: Thank you, you solved part of my problem, now what if I have 3 inputFields that the total selected fields from all of them have to be less than 3

Comment: You can add `onchange="validate(this);"` to all of them.

Comment: yea but that will give 3 options for each inputField, what I need is that the user can select 3 options in total like ( 2,0,1 or 1,1,1)

Comment: I updated my answer to store all selections instead of selections from a single multi-select. Make sure all multi-select inputfields have the `validate(this);` function attached to the `onchange` event.